# Create MySQL CHILD and PARENT records at the same time and set CHILD.PARENT_ID by using MySQL Triggers

Tags: mysql, trigger, mariadb

I want to create relationships between parent and child when booth doesn't exist and when new child is created. This somehow can be done with Triggers but i don't know how to work with SQL.

After some googling i came up with Trigger concept bellow.

1. Create child
2. Create parent
3. Get last parent id
4. Update **CURRENT** child record with parent_id

Could somebody help me to achieve this?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `database_name`.`trigger_name` AFTER INSERT
    ON `database_name`.`child_table`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    /*Step 1 - Create Parent record.*/
    INSERT INTO  `database_name`.`parent_table`(id) VALUES (``);

    /*Step 2 - Get last inserted ID of just created Parent record 
      and assign to the variable*/
    DECLARE last_id int;

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID INTO last_id;
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name = `parent_table`
    AND table_schema = `database_name`;

    /*Step 3 - Update current record child_table.parent_id with last_id variable*/
    UPDATE NEW.parent_id = last_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Or something like this, but it has errors.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS create_new_child; $$

CREATE 
    TRIGGER create_new_child BEFORE INSERT
    ON child
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE last_id INT;
        SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT INTO last_id
        FROM information_schema.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = parent
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();
    INSERT INTO parent (title) VALUES (`TEST`);
    SET NEW.parent_id = last_id;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Unknown column 'parent' in 'where clause'

Comment: Shouldn't parent row be inserted if not exists?

Comment: Can you shed some light on the problem you're trying to solve here?  What's the use of having a parent without a single known fact, apart from having a child record?

Comment: Hi. Parent SHOULD be created when CHILD is inserted. After that i need to get `PARENT_ID` and to SET in my `CHILD.PARENT_ID`.
`ID`s = PK with auto-increment.
`PARENT_ID` = FK to `PARENT.ID` and NULL is allowed. So i can insert CHILD records without `PARENT_ID` and update it after.

Comment: Parents does not exist at moment of creation child. There is 1:1 relation. Parents currently are used just as internal middleman but they are important in future development. So i cant have child records without a parent.

Comment: A newbie should not work with Triggers.  Instead, build a transaction:  `BEGIN; 2 inserts in the right order; COMMIT;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to perform this trigger before insert child row and there is a lot of errors in your code.

1. You must declare variables in the beginning of the script.
2. You give values to variables with SET
3. Only LAST_INSERT_ID() function is necessary and if you perform the trigger before update, you only have to set NEW value, and that's it.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER `database_name `.`trigger_name` $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `database_name `.`trigger_name` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `database_name `.`child_table`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE last_id int;
    INSERT INTO  `database_name`.`parent_table`(id) VALUES (0);

    SET NEW.parent_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, i am not programmer. Trying to google this stuff so sorry for mistakes. Your example didn't worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Finally got it working!

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS create_new_child; $$

CREATE 
    TRIGGER create_new_child BEFORE INSERT
    ON child
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE last_id INT;
        SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT INTO last_id
        FROM information_schema.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'parent'
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();
    INSERT INTO parent (title) VALUES ('TEST');
    SET NEW.parent_id = last_id;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: No!  If someone else slips in, they can get _your_ `last_id`.

Comment: What do You mean? This is a BEFORE INSERT trigger. Execution is in some NS. You mean that there is practical chance that 2 different transactions can get the same last_id? Then i will have some kind of error because of constraints.

Comment: `information_schema` is _probably_ not transactionally locked such that the id can be safely grabbed.  It would be much better to somehow use the approved `last_insert_id()` to get the value.

Comment: Is it possible to use something like this `LAST_INSERT_ID()++`?

Comment: There is no `++` operator.  This _expression_ should work:  `LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1`.  _But NOT in this context._  That 'function' only has a value after an insert involving `AUTO_INCREMENT` -- which is _not_ your case.